# What is the correct way to implement server timer in intraweb usersession

Tags: delphi, timer, intraweb

I have a simple intraweb project with the following structure

Usersession :
Have a timer to check the database and load the changes, do some data-formatting and put the results into a in memory table.

MainForm :
Have a IWTimer to check if the in memory table in Usersession changed and update its content if needed.

I do not use the IWTimer to check the database directly because I do not want some wait time in the browser which affect user experience.

The problem is that the usersession seems do not have a message queue and normal timer won't work.  So, I used JvThreadTimer in Jedi VCL instead.  I create it in UserSession.Create event and Stop and Free it in Destroy Event.  It do the work fine.

However, when I close the server application, it immediately pop up EidClosedSocket with message 'Disconnected'.  The exception fired before the Destroy Events in MainForm / Usersession / ServerControl Unit so I cannot find a way to stop the Timer before it trigger the exception.

So is there a proper way to set up a server side timer in usersession or are there other way of doing the periodical database checking which do not affect browser usage?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First. Don't use VCL stuff and window handle relying stuff within a non window application like a service/webserver.

The easiest way to fullfill that requierement is to use a Thread with an event object which is dispatched when the application starts.

It should look something like this:

```
type
  TTimerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fSig : TSimpleEvent;
    procedure DoTimer;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    procedure SignalTerminate;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

{ TSessionGarbageCollector }

constructor TTimerThread .Create;
begin
     fSig := TSimpleEvent.Create;

     inherited Create(False);
end;

destructor TTimerThread.Destroy;
begin
     fSig.Free;

     inherited;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.Execute;
begin
     try
        // e.g. every 10 seconds
        while fSig.WaitFor(10000) = wrTimeout do
        begin
             if Terminated then
                break;

             try
                // #################################################
                // #### Run the garbage collector from time to time
                DoTimer;
             except
                   on E : Exception do
                   begin
                        // your timer specific exception handling here
                   end;
             end;
        end;
     except
           on F : Exception do
           begin
                // your global exception handling here 
           end;
     end;
end;

procedure TSessionGarbageCollector.DoTimer;
begin
     // whatever you like your timer to do
end;

procedure TSessionGarbageCollector.SignalTerminate;
begin
     Terminate;

     fSig.SetEvent;
end;
```

Also note that you should not dispatch the thread within the initialization clause if your module is a dll (like an isapi dll). Look for a place where you know that dllmain has already been processed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I had test your code and the problem is exactly same as using TJvThreadTimer.  Actually, your code do similar work with TJvThreadTimer.  The problem is that I cannot find a place to call the Thread to stop before the exception raised.  Also, the exception is not happened in the excute method as the on exception did not triggered.

Comment: what exception? you need to show some code so we can view how you use the timer. to stop this thread you need to call aTimer.SignalTerminate; aTimer.WaitFor; aTimer.Free; in that sequence.

Comment: the exception has already been in the question.   EidClosedSocket with message 'Disconnected'.  I added two property to your code which is interval and OnTimer Event.  I Create the object in the OnCreate event of the usersession.  It worked well calling the OnTimer event every interval.  However, When I kill active session or close the build-in debug form.  The EidClosedSocket exception popup.  The call stack show that It is in InIOHandler.  Your terminating procedure is ok as far as there is a place to put it which can be executed before the exception.

Comment: The exception is a completely different story.  This exception has nothing to do with the timer itself. If that is happening inside the timer routine you need to handle/swallow it there (don't let exceptions escape from threads).

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I know the exception did not happen directly in the timer.  But it exist only where there is an active thread timer.  That's why I am asking what is the correct way to implement a timer in this situation.